# Git & Python : How to removed a cache/pycache of a deleted folder?

Tags: python, git, caching

Let's say my project structure looks like the below

```
Main Folder
- SubCode Folder
- SubTest Folder
```

I want to delete everything cache from that subtest folder including the folder itself.
How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried `git rm --cached ....` ?

Comment: I tried ``git rm --cached Main/SubTest`` but it said ``fatal: Invalid path '/Main': No such file or directory``